# Value undefined in express route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have declared this method here

```
exports.postRedisValue = function(req,res) {
        
    let keyRedis = req.body.key;
    let valueRedis = req.body.value;

    console.log(keyRedis); //throws undefined 
    if(keyRedis && valueRedis){
    client.setex(
        keyRedis,3600,valueRedis);
        res.send(`Key and value are now set key is ${keyRedis} and value ${valueRedis}`);
    }else{
        res.send("Missing key or value");
    }

}
```

When i am trying to create a key and a value in redis through a form

In routes.js I have declared the route

```
router.post('/createKeyValue',redisController.postRedisValue);
```

In the server.js I have declared starting point

```
const redisRoute = require('../routes/routes');

const app = express();

const PORT = 3001;
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded()); 

app.use("/redisLogic",redisRoute);



app.listen(PORT,() =>{
    console.log("SERVER r");
})
```

But it keeps throwing undefined variable when trying to send a post request to /redisLogic/createKeyValue. What am i missing ?

The request that is being sent

[image]

Comment: Show us the POST request.

Comment: See the answer down, you only need `body-parser` for this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you have not made use of `body-parser` npm package in your application.

Try using `body-parser` npm [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)

**Install it with.**

`npm install --save body-parser`

And inside your node app, use it with

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser);
```

Comment: @Thymeleaf can you specify the version of Express that you are making use of?

Comment: its @types/express@4.17.13

Comment: @Thymeleaf can you try sending the request as `JSON` use raw ffrom the radio fild and JSON from the dropdown that appears after that. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zkviw.png

Comment: Nah wait i added  app.use(express.json()) and now its working